# Dynamically create and remove a control from a form, many times

Tags: vb.net, controls, dispose, dynamically-generated

The below subroutine, when called using a mouse click, successfully creates and then removes a control. but it doesn't create it a second time. I'm assuming it is because the label is not longer dimensioned as public. ie `Dim lblDebug1 As New Label` is at the top variable section of the form.
However when I put `Dim lblDebug1 As New Label` in the subroutine the dispose request doesn't work. Is there someway that I can keep creating and disposing a control?

In the below sub, `booleanDebug` is used to switch back and forth between creating it and disposing it. *Thanks* in advance.

```
Dim lblDebug1 As New Label

booleanDebug = Not booleanDebug
  If booleanDebug Then
      Me.Controls.Add(lblDebug1)
      lblDebug1.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
  Else
      lblDebug1.Dispose()
  End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the label has a global context.  Within the form that owns it and that you have all the appropriate size and coordinates information and visibility set.

Here is some sample code that worked for me.  First just create a new windows form then add a button control in the middle of the form then use the following code.

```
Public Class Main
Private labelDemo As Windows.Forms.Label

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.SuspendLayout()

    If labelDemo Is Nothing Then

        labelDemo = New Windows.Forms.Label
        labelDemo.Name = "label"
        labelDemo.Text = "You Click the Button"
        labelDemo.AutoSize = True
        labelDemo.Left = 0
        labelDemo.Top = 0
        labelDemo.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Violet
        Me.Controls.Add(labelDemo)

    Else
        Me.Controls.Remove(labelDemo)
        labelDemo = Nothing
    End If

    Me.ResumeLayout()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I put `Public lblDebug1 As New Label` at the top of the form, but I think `Dim..` made it global as well.  I put `lblDebug1.Visible = True` on the list of properties to set. However, like before, if first created it, then disposed of it, and then when it went to create it again, it said I can't change the visibility of a Disposed object. That is after it executed `Me.Controls.Add(lblDebug1)`

Comment: Is the Dim statement inside the method or is it declared elsewhere, perhaps at the top of the form somwhere?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...@Christ, When `Public lblDebug1 As New Label` is at the top of the form, the subroutine successfully creates and then removes the control. but it doesn't create it a second time.When `Dim lblDebug1 As New Label` is in the subroutine the dispose request doesn't work.   @jcwrequests ,I've posted it on Gist, here is the link https://gist.github.com/Dave1235/6633144. It is called CreateDisposeCreatelabel . I'm not sure I did it right however. Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay I think I understand and when I get on my laptop latter I will put some code together for you. Right now I am on my tablet.

Comment: I revised my answer let me know if I can add anything else to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks jcw. It looks like you are trying to teach me some good programing habits while you're at it :) . If I understand right, the use of nothing is better than toggling a flag because you have fewer "balls in the air". I didn't know about suspending the layout, that's good to know. I'm relatively new at this. _Thanks_ again.

Comment: No problem. For situation like this I often find it's just easier to check the object or control for nothing. BTW did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've Disposed a control, you can't use it any more. You have two choices here:

**Choice 1:** Just Remove the control from the form rather than disposing it:

```
'Top of the file
Dim lblDebug1 As New Label

'Button click
booleanDebug = Not booleanDebug
If booleanDebug Then 
    lblDebug1.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
    Me.Controls.Add(lblDebug1)       
Else
    Me.Controls.Remove(lblDebug1)
End If
```

**Choice 2:** Create a new control object each time

```
'Top of the file
Dim lblDebug1 As Label
'               ^   No "New". 
'We just want an object reference we can share at this point, no need for an instance yet

'Button click
booleanDebug = Not booleanDebug
If booleanDebug Then
    lblDebug1 = New Label()
    lblDebug1.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
    Me.Controls.Add(lblDebug1)
Else
    lblDebug1.Dispose()
End If
```

Comment: _Thanks_ for your time Joel. Choice 2 looks like it will suit my needs.